# Finding the least common ancestor of two nodes in a tree

Tags: c++, tree, nodes

I was given this question in an interview, and I failed to answer it even though I know how to solve the problem. The reason I didn't know what to do is because the question was given to me like this:

```
class Node{
      int val;
      Node *left, *right;
};

int LCA(int a, int b){
     //your code here
}
```

The interviewer wanted me to find the least common ancestor of a and b. I asked whether we were given a pointer to the root of the tree we're searching through, and he said no. So I was confused as to how I should solve the problem given I don't even have a tree to work with.

Is it possible to find the least common ancestor in this case? Should I have assumed we were given a global `Node*` that was the root of the tree or something? Has anyone experienced a similar problem?

Comment: How can you operate on a tree if you are not given a tree upon which to operate? Maybe the LCA() function  is supposed to be a member function of the class?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Node LCA(Node a, Node b)` if `a` and `b` are `Nodes` and the ancestor returned is also a `Node`?

Comment: @chiliNUT That's what I thought. The interviewer was persistent about this being the "correct" format for the question, despite me asking multiple times. I suppose my suspicions that he was wrong are correct. However, even given two Nodes, how can you find their LCA without a Node to the root of the tree?

Comment: The interviewer was wrong.

Comment: I think a more interesting question would be, how can you prove that the interviewer is wrong by showing without the root node or some kind of parent backlink node, the problem cannot be solved.

Comment: @greatwolf If the function prototype had been Node* LCA(Node *a, Node *b), we still cannot solve the question, right?

Comment: @BobJohn Ignoring the function prototype, this is really easily solvable.

Comment: From what I can tell, you can only find a solution to that problem if either `a` is a child in `b`'s branch or visa versa in which case, one would be the LCA of the other. If they're on divergent branches then you can't solve it since you cannot backtrack.

Comment: @2501 I could have solved it no problem if the problem were properly defined. But when I was forced to use that specific function I didn't know what to do.

Comment: @greatwolf by using the parametricity theorem.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible. To answer the question you were given you need to be able to find a path between a node and its ancestors. For this you need either the node as a starting point and a reference to parent in each node. Or the ancestor (or an ancestor of the ancestor) as a starting point and references to children in each node.

Answer (score 1):

From the way you have described the interview interaction, I suspect this was a trick question. Probably a weak attempt to see if you are persistent with your questions for clarification.

If it were me, after getting the feedback that there is no root, I would ask if there is some other way the node values are related to each other. If the nodes have a mathematical relationship, you may not require a root node to solve the LCA problem.

Another tactic would be to determine how nodes are inserted, removed, and found. That is, figure out what APIs are available. You may have discovered that the interviewer would have provided a parent API.

Sometimes, an interview is like a game of Adventure, and the interviewer really wants you to find your way out of the twisty maze (however unfair it may seem).